# Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

Trying to run an MVC5 app on IIS 7.5 2008-R2 server gives the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I don't know why this happens. I'm definitely not using RIA, the app is entirely pure MVC 5 and the exactly same app runs OK on another server (IIS 7.5 W 2012 R2 ).
I use to have a Silverlight project on this server (2008 R2), but it has been removed long time ago.

I've compared the IIS settings on both servers and they are the same. I've reinstalled the same ASP.Net framework v 4.5.1 I've even installed RIA on the server, but nothing seems to remove this error.

I've also looked at several threads on SO and the Internet related to this topic and tried some of them, but at no results.

At this point and time, I have no idea on what else to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove any `Web.config` section that contains this

```
<system.web>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="DomainServiceModule" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </httpModules>
  <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
```

or this

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="DomainServiceModule" preCondition="managedHandler"
        type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

see [Guide to deploying RIA services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff426912(v=vs.91).aspx)

Comment: This allowed the application to run without run time errors. But I was promted with a silverlight installation every time i visit the page instead of seeing the application, inspite of already having installing it.

Comment: OK, nevermind your answer was specific to OP's question where he was not using silverlight.